# Using Windows sounds when displaying JOptionPane windows

Tags: java, windows, swing, awt, joptionpane

How would I play whichever sound the user has set for exclamation when I display `JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE` or the error sound when I display `JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE`, for example?

Comment: *"Using Windows sounds when displaying JOptionPane windows"*  That won't work on OS X or *nix (fortunately).  A relatively x-plat alternative is [`Toolkit.beep()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#beep%28%29).

Comment: hmm .. the optionPane should do so by default (iff the OS supports sounds and the user has turned on the option for playing system them on the OS level - which I personally wouldn't do, ever, so didn't test ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the links MadProgrammer provided (reposted at the end) as a starting point, here's what I figured out:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

//retrieve the default sound from windows system sounds
//for another sound replace "default" accordingly
    final Runnable SOUND = (Runnable)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getDesktopProperty
    ("win.sound.default");
```

and then just before displaying the JOptionPane:

```
if(SOUND != null)SOUND.run();
```

*NB* Some sound events like Program Error cannot be accessed this way. A list of  accessible sound events is available under the audio-feedback heading on the [Windows Desktop Property Support](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html) page from Oracle

While this will not work at all on a non-windows o/s, it will not, according to [the blog](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2010/01/03/playing-default-system-sounds-java), cause the program to crash on another o/s.  I don't have a `JDK` for my Linux partition yet, ergo I am currently unable to test this.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption - *nothing special required to do, JOptionPane just does it* - was based on skimming BasicOptionPaneUI code and checking if the optionPane's audioActionMap is installed.

The place where the audio is played is in the ui's propertyChangeListener on a change to its ancestor property:

```
if ("ancestor" == e.getPropertyName()) {
    JOptionPane op = (JOptionPane)e.getSource();
    boolean isComingUp;

    // if the old value is null, then the JOptionPane is being
    // created since it didn't previously have an ancestor.
    if (e.getOldValue() == null) {
        isComingUp = true;
    } else {
        isComingUp = false;
    }

    // figure out what to do based on the message type
    switch (op.getMessageType()) {
    case JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE:
        if (isComingUp) {
            BasicLookAndFeel.playSound(optionPane,
                               "OptionPane.informationSound");
        }
        break;
    // all other message types handled as well
}
```

the shared actionMap is installed (lazyly, so an optionPane must have been visible once)

```
assertTrue(UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.actionMap") instanceof ActionMap);
ActionMap map = (ActionMap) UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.actionMap");
assertNotNull(map.get("OptionPane.errorSound"));
```

sounds enabled on OS (win 7) level and sound on hardware turned on (just for testing) ... WTF: but nothing happens (and assumption proven to be wrong ;-)

Debug session (I hate it ... but occasionally ...) turns out that performing the audioAction doesn't happen, here are the methods involved :

```
static void playSound(JComponent c, Object actionKey) {
    LookAndFeel laf = UIManager.getLookAndFeel();
    if (laf instanceof BasicLookAndFeel) {
        ActionMap map = c.getActionMap();
        if (map != null) {
            Action audioAction = map.get(actionKey);
            if (audioAction != null) {
                // pass off firing the Action to a utility method
                // JW: we have an audioAction, so on to the next method
                ((BasicLookAndFeel)laf).playSound(audioAction);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void playSound(Action audioAction) {
    if (audioAction != null) {
        Object[] audioStrings = (Object[])
                                UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.playList");
        if (audioStrings != null) {
           // JW: here the action is performed ... except we don't reach this
           ....
        }

}
```

That's rather astonishing, isn't it? After all, the action were created, so if there is no playlist, why would they have been created?

And here comes the catch: the list used for creating the actions is a different list

```
// in BasicLookAndFeel
protected ActionMap getAudioActionMap() {
    ActionMap audioActionMap = (ActionMap)UIManager.get(
                                          "AuditoryCues.actionMap");
    if (audioActionMap == null) {
        // here it's named cueList
        Object[] acList = (Object[])UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.cueList");

}
```

and the reason that's a different list is ... to allow LAFs to customize the sounds that actually are to be played

```
// BasicLookAndFeel
// *** Auditory Feedback
"AuditoryCues.cueList", allAuditoryCues,
// this key defines which of the various cues to render.
// L&Fs that want auditory feedback NEED to override playList.
"AuditoryCues.playList", null,
```

Ooookaaayy .. so let's see what a concrete LAF is doing, f.i. Win:

```
// *** Auditory Feedback
// this key defines which of the various cues to render
// Overridden from BasicL&F. This L&F should play all sounds
// all the time. The infrastructure decides what to play.
// This is disabled until sound bugs can be resolved.
"AuditoryCues.playList", null, // table.get("AuditoryCues.cueList"),
```

EOL.

Not quite :-) This comment hints to what is doable:

```
Object[] cueList = (Object[]) UIManager.get("AuditoryCues.cueList");
UIManager.put("AuditoryCues.playList", cueList);
```

Which in fact does work for WindowsLAF (even respecting the OS sound schema and - most importantly - *not* playing if disabled), but not for any of the other core LAFs.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I agree with Andrew

However, take a look [here](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/mkarg/archive/2010/01/03/playing-default-system-sounds-java) then [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/swing/1.4/w2k_props.html)

Ps I've not tested this myself

Comment: my assumption is that there's nothing special needed, see my comment to the question. Didn't try, though.

Comment: @kleoatra I'd be nice if it did, can't say I've seen it happen though (but I turn most these sounds off personally). The other problem with my solution is you'd have to configure it yourself, that is, before showing any option dialogs, you'd have to play the sound yourself